# Tridion 2011 SP1 : Issue while deploying the content

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are using Tridion 2011 sp1 without any hotfix and .net web application httpupload.aspx to deploy the content in filesystem.
We monitored and found there are two issues:

1) Some time pages those are published successfully in the publishing queue are not uploaded/updated in the file system.

2) Transport package is not created for the pages which are getting failed with the error:

Deploying FailedPhase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory, Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory

Also in the deployer log file and transporter log file, there is no reference to failed item transaction id.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Have you got your logging level configured as "debug"? If not, doing so might give you more insight into the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You must have some more detail on the failure in your logs than just this.

Could not initialize StorageManagerFactory will typically point to a misconfigured cd_storage_conf.xml or a jar missing.

If you get this occasionally then there must be something that fails occasionally (like your database connection or a file system).

Please scan through your deployer and/or core logs for additional information.

[UPDATE]

I think you may have a second deployer "listening" to the same incoming directory, and that 2nd deployer is broken.

Hints of that:

1. You say no transport package is created. I assume you mean you can't find the transport package - it must be created in the CM otherwise it can't fail. This means "someone" picked it up
2. "Sometimes they're published, sometimes not" == Sometimes they're picked up by the right deployer, sometimes they're picked up by the wrong one.
3. No references to the transaction in the logs

Search your server for all cd_deployer_conf.xml, and go compare all your "incoming" folder settings. You can only have one deployer per incoming folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I updated my post with few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1) In the windows event logs identify the path of the Deployer that is getting loaded...generally it should be define by the Tridion_Home variable but there is also a roll up logic in place and it might also get picked up the deployer path from your application config on priority if you have placed the deployer config and bin folders with in your application bin folder for processing by the Tridion Content Delivery API

2) Check if the updated SQL JDBC jar file is present in the deployer bin folder

3) Verify that you do not have jre version between 1.6.0.26 to 1.6.0.30 installed on CMA and/or CDA server - check for both 32-bit as well as 64-bit version